# why is nothing displaying when I run my php code using mamp

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have created a page with an image slide showing jQuery. I also have a search that that a user can search for a house from a database and this code works find. When I added php code in so that the user is allowed to log in and tried to run it the page comes up blank, why is this?

Here is my code

```html
session_start();

  include "connect.php";

  if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = ($con "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password= '$password'");

$result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

}else {

echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";

}


if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

echo "Hello " . $username . "";
echo "This is the Members Area";

echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

}
?>
```

Comment: You should limit the code to the sections related to your problem.

Comment: sorry I thought that it was everything within the page the was making it not work

Comment: I think that was a error when I copied over the code

Comment: You're doing the same thing as your other question earlier, one that I answered. Not passing DB connection to your query `$result = mysqli_query($query)` --- `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)`

Comment: I noticed that but it doesn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: Please update your question with the new code you are now using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're not passing your connection to your query and you have one missing brace.

The one for `if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']))` which should encapsulate your entire PHP.

Sidenote: Using `$con` as the connection variable's parameter.

```
<?php
session_start();

  include "connect.php";

  if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

}else {

echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";

}


if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

echo "Hello " . $username . "";
echo "This is the Members Area";

}

} // closing brace for if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']))

echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

?>
```

---

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).